# Svelte/Sapper.js - How to initialize store with localStorage data?

Tags: javascript, state, server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper

I come from a React background, but I'm switching to Svelte and Sapper for my next application in order to fight the massive bundle size that comes with React these days. However, I'm having trouble initializing Svelte's store with data retrieved from localStorage.

As per the Sapper docs (https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Getting_started), I created my project by running `npx degit "sveltejs/sapper-template#rollup" my-app` from the command line. I then installed the dependencies and removed the demo code in the `src` folder.

I then created two files: `src/routes/index.svelte` and `src/store/index.js`.

Code for both:

**src/store/index.js**

```
    import {writable} from "svelte/store";
    
    export let userLang;
    
    if(typeof window !== "undefined") {
        userLang = writable(localStorage.getItem("lang") || "en");
    } else {
        userLang = writable(null);
    }
```

**src/routes/index.svelte**

```
    <script>
        import {userLang} from "../store";
    </script>
    
    <p>Your Preferred Language: {$userLang}</p>
```

When I run the application and hit the `index` route, I see this:

> Your Preferred Language: null

which then almost immediately updates and changes to

> Your Preferred Language: en

when there is no `lang` item in localStorage, and changes to

> Your Preferred Language: fr

After explicitly setting `localStorage.setItem("lang", "fr")` from the developer console and refreshing.

I know that the store is being initialized on the server first where `window` is `undefined` and then is being rehydrated on the client. So this behavior is expected.

So my question is: how can I skip the server initialization entirely? Is it possible to only set up the store on the client (where `localStorage` is defined) so that the user's chosen language is immediately available?

I can't default to having everything in English or any other language after the user has chosen to change their preferred language. I also can't get the user language from the browser via `navigator.language` on initial page load either since `navigator` is `undefined` on the server as well.

And having a flash of empty text appear before the store rehydrates would screw up the UX for my application, especially when the value of `userLang` is going to be used all over the place with translations.

So any strategies or hacks for this are definitely appreciated.

**** **Deeper Issue** ****

I would actually prefer to **not** have server-side rendering at all for this application, but I do need all the other excellent features that Sapper provides, like routing, prefetching, and static site building.

So I tried running `npx sapper export` as per the [docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#sapper_export) to generate a completely static site in an effort to remove the server from the equation, but the exact same issue still occurs, even though there is no server being used at all.

Does anyone have any advice on how to configure Sapper and turn off SSR but keep the other features?

Thank you!

**** **Update** ****

As per Rich Harris's answer, wrapping the markup with `{#if process.browser}` does the trick just fine. So I've updated the `src/routes/index.svelte`file like so:

```
    <script>
        import {userLang} from "../store";
    </script>

    {#if process.browser}
        <p>Your Preferred Language: {$userLang}</p>
    {/if}
```

And the `userLang` variable is immediately set with the value from `localStorage` or defaults to `en` as I intended for this simple demo. There is no more flash of `null`, so it's essentially behaving like it's client-side only at this point.

I will work on fleshing out my project and see if there are any more issues I encounter. Til then, I think this solves my issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At present, SSR is non-optional. There's an issue open for an SPA mode — https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/383 — that would behave as you describe, we just need to get round to it.

We also plan to have built-in support for i18n in a future release: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/576

In the meantime, you can fake it by wrapping all your markup in `{#if process.browser}` — anything inside won't be server rendered, but will be present as soon as JavaScript kicks in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will definitely be keeping an eye on those issues and will try wrapping the markup in the if block as you said. And also thanks for the all around awesomeness that is Svelte. I know that the project will only get better and better as time goes on

Comment: My token is stored in localStorage, how do I get around that with sapper?

Comment: It's worth noting that checking `process.browser` also appears to work in regular JS code, not just in templates. Thanks!

Comment: process.browser works in my build environment. but it doesn't work when i export.