# How to persist UI component state data in Sapper?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

In a Sapper app, I want to be able to persist the state of some UI components so I can navigate the app without losing state when the user returns to the pages using those components.

In a Svelte-only app, this is usually done with a custom store that uses the `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` API. A good example of that can be found in R. Mark Volkmann's book *Svelte and Sapper in Action*, §6.24:

`store-util.js`

```js
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

function persist(key, value) {
  sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

export function writableSession(key, initialValue) {
  const sessionValue = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
  if (!sessionValue) persist(key, initialValue);

  const store = writable(sessionValue || initialValue);
  store.subscribe(value => persist(key, value));
  return store;
}
```

Unfortunately, using stores that way breaks immediately in Sapper because the scripts run on the server first, where `sessionStorage` is not defined. There are ways to prevent some parts of code from running on the server (using the `onMount` lifecycle function in a component, or checking `process.browser === true`), but that doesn't seem possible here.

Persisting some state locally looks like a very common use case so I'm wondering what's the right way to do it in a Sapper app (considering that I haven't even found the wrong way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a dummy store for SSR.

It is always possible to do feature detection with something like `typeof localStorage !== 'undefined'`.

Your component code will re-run in the browser, even if the page was SSR'd. This means that if it is fed a different store, the browser-only values will take over and update existing state (inherited from the server).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65600835/1387519) for an example.