# How do I avoid preloading the same data multiple times in a Sapper app?

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper

I am new to Sapper and am trying to figure out how to handle data from an API that should be shared across multiple routes.

Take for example a logged in user object from an API. There are multiple routes where I would need this data and want it to be preloaded, but don't want to fetch the data from my API more than once (I believe I am right in thinking that the `preload` function will run on each page navigation).

In an SPA built with plain Svelte, I would fetch this kind of data once on the client and use a store to share the data between the pages.

It doesn't seem possible to access stores in my `preload` function, so how do I share this data between routes?

Comment: You have to implement this user-object as singleton? Do you have some code?

Comment: No, it wouldn't necessarily have to be a singleton. I don't have any code yet, I am just considering how I would solve this kind of problem of needing the same data for multiple different routes but only wanting to fetch it once.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65740245/how-to-persist-ui-component-state-data-in-sapper points in your direction?